# Commandline : How to Pair *two* Raspberry Pi's over Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and a Raspberry Pi Zero-W: both of which have built-in Bluetooth.

How can I pair these two machines together  ? Both are headless systems.

Once they are paired - will 'obexftp' be the most sensible way of sending files between them ? Or better to set up 'pan' between them ?

Comment: What do you mean *set up 'pan' between them*?  Doesn't pairing via Bluetooth - by definition - create a Personal Area Network (PAN)?  Otherwise. the only Raspbian software package I can find named `pan` is a newsreader, so I don't think you're talking about a particular piece of software.

Comment: I think I meant a 'piconet' - which (I believe) is a specific Bluetooth profile.

Comment: But basically: I meant a way of running 'IP' over Bluetooth. ('bnep' device or something?)

Comment: Maybe I should have checked first... there is, in fact, a [PAN profile](http://www.conniq.com/Bluetooth/Bluetooth_profile_03.htm) for Bluetooth.  It looks like it does something like IP over Bluetooth.

Comment: No worries - I should have been more specific (but the problem is I don't know what I need to do here - I think I need the 'pand' daemon working on one system - which is also running a Bluetooth 'access point' )

Answer (score 2):

### Adapt Intel Edison Guide, Use `obexftp`

I found a guide that describes [pairing two Intel Edisons](http://stephaniemoyerman.com/?p=100) using `bluetoothctl`.  It should work for two Raspberry Pi's, since they have the same software.

It basically goes like this:

1. On both, set KeyboardDisplay agent (and default-agent?)
2. On slave, set pairable and discoverable
3. On master, scan and pair with slave MAC (confirm passkey)
4. On slave, trust master MAC
5. On master, connect to slave MAC

Once you're paired, I think it would be simpliest if you used `obexftp` for the file transfers, since you've only got two devices, and messing with profiles would probably be more complicated.

---

Note: I usually try to include specific commands from the links I put in answers, but I would have to copy so much from this blog post that I'd be uncomfortable doing so.

Comment: Website is down, but cached at Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20161105175445/http://stephaniemoyerman.com/?p=100